# Problemas con ComboBox column en C#

Tags: c#, sql, windows-forms

estoy desarrollando un sistema de ventas y tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un DGV con una columna tipo combobox; entonces quiero que al agregar un nuevo producto el de esa primera fila tenga sus precios correspondientes, y si lleno otra fila, tenga sus precios correspondientes sin que la fila anterior pierda sus precios. De momento he podido hacer la parte de cargar los datos a la columna combobox con este código:

```
string srch = "Select Tipo from DetArticulos where CodigoArt = '" + dgvFactura.CurrentRow.Cells["Codigo"].Value.ToString() + "'";
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn Tipo = dgvFactura.Columns["Unidad"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;
Tipo.DataSource = funcion.CargarCombo(srch);
Tipo.DisplayMember = "Tipo";
```

como notaran, hace referencia a un modulo de función, este es el código que esta aya.

```
public DataTable CargarCombo(string SqlStr)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        MiAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlStr, con);
        MiData = new DataTable();
        MiAdap.Fill(MiData);
        return MiData;
    }

    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

En fin, me da el siguiente error cuando agrego un segundo producto.
[image: Error]
Quisiera ver que soluciones me dan ademas.

Comment: o sea, tu problema es que estas cargando el mismo combo para todas las filas???

Comment: mas o menos: te lo detallo mas. Tengo un precio asignado a una unidad de medida, esa unidad es la que cargare al CBox, entoces. de primeras funciona bien. cuando cargo el segundo articulo, el primero toma la unidades del 2do y cuando intento cargar las unidades correspondientes al primero ocurre el error que ves en la imagen

Comment: Este es un error comun. El combo box, es el mismo para todas las filas, con lo cual, no podes andar cambiandolo. para ellos, creo que habia respuestas ya en el sitio, porque implican no usar el combo, y sobreescribir al momento de la edicion la celda... no es una tarea sencilla.. fijate si encuentras mas info por ahi...